# Are the two "tos" the same in "worked ... *to* identify" and *came home *to* find"?

Tags: infinitives

> But Stephen, who is not a scientist, had his family’s genomes
>    sequenced and worked with geneticist Ryan Taft at the University of
>    Queensland in Australia **to** identify a mutated gene. Taft linked
>    the gene to a class of neurodegenerative disorders involving the
>    myelin sheath, which protects neurons.
>   [Nature](http://www.nature.com/news/personal-responsibility-1.18269)

Can this to be interpreted as "and identified a mutated gene..."?
As in

> He came home **to** find his mother dead?

Answer (score 2):

The use of the word 'to' implies a stronger connection between the 'working' and the 'identifying'; the identification is a (possible) *result* of the work done.

Compare the following sentences:

> He worked hard to solve the problem.
>
> He worked hard and solved the problem.

The first sentence does not imply that he actually solved the problem, only that he worked very hard on it.

The second sentence *could* be used to describe a situation like this:

> He worked hard, and solved the problem eventually, because he found the solution on StackExchange.

Comment: In fact, *he worked to identify the gene* does not necessarily imply that he actually did identify the gene, only that he tried to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your *tos* act as infinitive markers; but the two clauses which these infinitives head are used very differently.

- In the first sentence, the clause designates the **purpose** for which the genetic work was carried out: identifying a mutant gene.

  > Thomas went home **to change** his clothes.
  >   We were marching **to protest** the government's action.
- In the second sentence, the clause designates the **situation** into which the subject has entered. This construction has a *telic* verb in the main clause—a verb which implies a change of state at the end of the verb's action—and a verb of perception or discovery in the infinitive whose object is the situation.

  > Thomas arrived home **to see** his front door wide open and the house robbed.
  >   We marched to the square **to discover** the police waiting for us in riot gear.

Answer (score 1):

The "to" in "to indentify" is an *infinitive marker*. There is no need **to** try **to** impute  (or **to** work **to** identify) any other meaning.